# What is the purpose of pin row header standoffs (the small legs or ribs on bandoliers)?

Tags: connector, insulation, header

Image of header documentation from Samtec with the standoff sections highlighted in yellow - note the lengths shown here are reverse usual headers i.e. the pin's short side is usually by the standoffs I'm asking about:

[image: Image of header documentation from Samtec with the standoff sections highlighted in yellow - note the lengths shown here are reverse usual headers i.e. the pin's short side is usually by the standoffs I'm asking about]

Most pin row headers have small standoffs / nubs / ribs / spacers on one side of the plastic bandolier/insulator, but why?

I've read in one place it is to facilitate cleaning, but they are usually present on SMT and 90° headers too which already have plenty of space for cleaning. Also, board-to-board headers (like these) usually (but not always) have both bandoliers in the same orientation, so the “upper” board would not be as cleanable.

I'm looking for the actual reason or reasons they are present, not speculation.

- I edited the question to add a diagram snipped from [Samtec documentation.](https://suddendocs.samtec.com/prints/tlw-1xx-xx-xxx-x-xx-xxx-mkt.pdf)

Comment: Pictures of what you are asking about would be very helpful and very welcome.

Comment: Precision long-life plastic injection molds (say SPI class 101) are rather expensive. So the presence where it not required is not as relevant as one might think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a few sources, cleaning does appear to be the/a primary purpose.

This [datasheet](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/bwb_bergstik-2.pdf) does talk about Pin In Paste technology for reflow, as well as the purpose of the standoffs being to allow cleaning. For reflow, being able to clean makes a LOT of sense, though I still think the orientation of the double-decker board-to-board connectors doesn't entirely align with that.

[This website](https://www.ett.bme.hu/meca/Courses/AIT/6_2.html) does show flux from wave soldering reaching the top side of the board.

To respond to an answer posted earlier, from what I read, hole filling is mainly due to capillary action, and the meniscus pushing solder through the holes (such that you'd need to space the plastic above it) would not be normal.

This isn't as definitive as I'd like, so I'm going to wait at least a day before up-voting it (if I understand SE, which is a very big if).